# Chart.js only draws when I go through debug on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to load a chart using Chart.JS on an AngularJS webpage. When I simply load the page, the chart does not draw even though the HTML element is in the page. I placed a console.log on the middle of the chart call only to be able to place a breakpoint on it. When I load the page with the breakpoint active, once I step over it the chart shows up! Anyone have any idea what could it be?

```
function fCurveChart(){
            new Chart(curveChart, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: $scope.labelsChart,
                    datasets:[{
                        label: '',
                        data: $scope.data[0],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(26,179,148,0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(26,179,148,1.5)',
                        borderWidth: 1.5,
                    },
                    {
                        label: '',
                        data: $scope.data[1],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(248, 172, 89, 0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(248, 172, 89, 1.5)',
                        borderWidth: 1.5,
                    }]             
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales:{
                        yAxes:[{
                            ticks:{
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            })
            console.log('ok')
        }
```

Comment: Have you defined your canvas and is it captured properly in curveChart variable ? Is your data coming from backend or kind of hard coded ?

Comment: It comes from backend. The canvas is defined, the chart loads properly after the debug

Comment: If the data is coming from backend, i will recommend, to debug, replace the api call with hard coded data and see if the chart loads. If yes it means ajax call timing and chart data loading is the issue. This method should only get called in the success handler of the ajax api call.

Comment: Did you try with hard coded data instead of an api call ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call fCurveChart() somewhere so that function will execute to render the chart. When you step through in debug mode, debug mode calls it.